# Cake php returns time string as a comment

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have this controller

```
public function admin_getsalesareas($house_id) {


       $this->autorender = false;
        $this->layout = false;
        $salesareas = $this->Salesarea->find('list', array('conditions' => array('house_id' => $house_id)));

        echo json_encode($salesareas);
    }
```

The problem is it returns a time string with the jason , which i don't want

```
{"1":"COA3","2":"tes1","3":"test2"} <!-- 0.1405s -->
```

How to remove that

Answer (score 1):

I think you have debug mode > 0 , to remove these please set debug to 0

```
Configure::write('debug', 0);
```